# How do I force mathematica to output more digits for this particular expression?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, digits

I'm working on a project where a certain calculation of $\pi$ to an arbitrary precision is required. I'm evaluating the below expression in Mathematica:

$6\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\left(-0.5\right)!\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(0.5\right)^{\left(2k+1\right)}}{\left(2k+1\right)\left(-0.5-k\right)!k!}\right)$

I have read the documentation pertaining to the use of arbitrary precision, and the function N[expr, n] where expr was replaced with the above expression seemed appropriate to me, and does work for other calculations. However, the output for my particular expression returns

3.141592653589793

which is only 16 digit accuracy, despite my n being a larger number. I have used the function NumberForm such that Mathematica displays all the digits it has stored.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do not use inexact numbers in the input. Anything containing a decimal point is "inexact". Anything containing a decimal point and no explicit precision specification after a backtick symbol is not only inexact, but also machine precision (meaning limited to ~15 digits and no precision tracking). **Thus, write `1/2` instead of `0.5`.**

Comment: Please see here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started, 1) take the introductory [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: How is this question even off-topic?? The OP asked how to achieve a desired level of precision in a mathematica calculation. Please reopen!

Answer (score 5):

To address the question, as was already mentioned in the comments if you want arbitrary precision use exact numbers. In this case, your expression can be written as

```
mypi[nmax_, n_] :=N[6 Sum[((-1/2)! (-1)^k (1/2)^(2 k +1))/((2 k + 1) (-1/2 - k)! k!), {k, 0, nmax}], n]
```

where nmax is the number of terms in the expansion and n the desired precision. For example, we can compare with the built-in symbol Pi by keeping 30 terms in your expansion:

```
In[4]:= mypi[30, 20]
N[Pi, 20]
Out[4]= 3.1415926535897932385
Out[5]= 3.1415926535897932385
```

A few comments:

a) If the project is written in Mathematica, it might be better to just use Pi in the calculations instead of calculating it yourself, as Pi is a symbol and carries arbitrary precision.

b) Be careful when using high values of nmax and/or n for the number of terms and the precision respectively, as you might run out of RAM quickly!

c) Mathematica is smart enough to recognize that your sum is Pi:

```
In[6]:= 6 Sum[((-1/2)! (-1)^ k (1/2)^(2 k + 1))/((2 k + 1) (-1/2 - k)! k!), {k, 0, \[Infinity]}]
Out[6]= \[Pi]
```

I hope this helps.